# How to add a context menu to a drawn rectangle?

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I want to add a context menu to dynamically drawn rectangles.
All rectangles are stored in a list. How do i do this?

```
foreach (Rectangle item in PadRects)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
            {
                Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.White, 1);
                g.DrawRectangle(mypen, item);
            }
        }
```

I want to show the context menu with a button to delete the rectangle.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide some code - what you've done so far ?

Comment: Easiest way is to turn each one into a control. Otherwise you have to do hit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `ContextMenuStrip` to your form.

Do NOT select it as the `ContextMenuStrip` property of your `pictureBox1` as this would open the context menu automatically. We don't want to do that, because we want to test whether the mouse is actually pointing to a drawn rectangle and only then open the context menu.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = PadRects
        .Where(r => r.Contains(e.Location))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (!rect.IsEmpty) {
        _clickedRectangle = rect; // Save the rectangle in a field to make it available
                                  // to the context menu item handler.
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(pictureBox1, e.Location);
    }
}
```